# How to make a Java class that prints out the following code

Tags: java, methods

I want to make a java class that would print out:

> The product of the two integers raised to powers 0 through 3 are:
>
> -2 times 9 raised to the power of 0 is 1.0
>
> -2 times 9 raised to the power of 1 is -18.0
>
> -2 times 9 raised to the power of 2 is 324.0
>
> -2 times 9 raised to the power of 3 is -5832.0"

I want to make this using a for loop, and each of the two integers needs to be from user input. I've figured out how to print it out using the System.out.print() but I haven't figured out how to make the loop, and how to make the exponents increasing using the for loop.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I think you are mixing 'Java' and 'JavaScript' terms.

Comment: Do you mean java or javascript? The fact that you are saying `System.out.print()` makes me 99% sure that you mean Java. The relationship between Java and Javascript is like the relationship between Car and Carpet.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a Math.pow function in a for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6038813/how-to-make-a-math-pow-function-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: Yes, I also think he means Java. I have placed the edit and it waits until is peer reviewed.

Comment: I've tried for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) { alert(Math.pow(input_number, i); }

Comment: but I need to find out how to use an int instead of (input_number) and still have the above result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how your loop might look.  You can fill in the details :-)

```
int num1 = -2;
int num2 = 9;

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    // i is the exponent
    // do something here with num1, num2, and i
    // print out the result
}
```

Comment: would it be... 


Math.pow(i)

i=(num1*num2)

System.out.print(i)

?